# Testing Tool that compare between the implemented website and it's design in pixels

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, web-testing

I have searched so many about a tool that compare between the implemented website and it's design and highlight the difference in pixels.

what I have found is only PerfectPixel extension which is not work as I want because the design is so big.

I will be thankful for any help in that.

hint: I have searched on that through google :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool:

http://galenframework.com/

Having design requirements you can write Galen specifications for specific screen resolutions and run tests against your implemented website.